# Cannot access the application using Public IP - err_timed_out

Tags: networking, jboss, dns, firewall, jboss-4.0.x

Our application is deployed in JBOSS 4.0 . We are facing this problem then and there, the application is accessible in localhost and when we try accessing using the public domain, the page cannot be accessed.

This is the error am getting in browser - the site cannot be reached error err_timed_out

At the same time we are able to ping the public ip successfully. I am not sure whether this is a network problem or the application. But after we restart the application server both the public and localhost are working fine.

Comment: Firewall blocking specific port?

Comment: Sadly am not able to access the production machine. The admin team told  that there is no issues with dns and firewall. I will ask them to check again.

But after we restart the JBOSS the public url which is https . Its working fine.

Comment: Is it possible that after the app server restart. The firewall will unblock the 443 port ?

Comment: Anything's possible if your sysadmins have crazy scripts :) But in general, the firewall configuration should never be updated after startup, or something like that. It's set up and that' it. Have you tried telnet to the IP:port ?

Comment: @cantSleepNow No, I didnt check the telnet . If this issue occur again I will make sure to check that next time .